# When a user clicks on a related blog, Reactjs requires them to refresh page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have React pages (BlogContent & RelatedBlog),

When a user views blog content, he can see below more blogs for the author. When the user clicks on the article he wants to read, the slug on Url changes but the content does not change until the user refreshes the page, so the user must refresh the page every time he wants to see all related blogs for the author.

I think the reason the blog page require refreshes every time is because useEffect() , but I don't know what is the trick to fix it

Here's my code to page BlogContent:

```
export const BlogContent = () => {

const { slug } = useParams();


const [data, setData] = useState({ posts: [] });

useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.get(slug).then((res) => {
        setData({ posts: res.data });
    });
}, [setData]);


let AuthorBlog = data.posts.author

};
```

and here for RelatedBlog

```
export const RelatedBlog = (props) => {

const { AuthorBlog } = props;


const [appState, setAppState] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    axiosInstance.get("/").then((res) => {
        const allBlogs = res.data;
        setAppState(allBlogs);
    });
}, [setAppState]);

const filterAuthor = appState.filter((item) => item.author === AuthorBlog) ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the whole App.js? Is there a Router as well or just the Route? Also, what version of react-router-dom do you use?

Comment: sure, thank you I edited App.js. yes, I add Router, the version of react-router is "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"

Comment: @George Makroglou and I apologize in advance for the size of the codes.

Comment: You should add `slug` to the dependency array of the `useEffect`

Comment: @Konrad Linkowski You are amazing; the problem has been resolved. But could you explain why slug must be added to the dependency array of the useEffect?

Comment: slug is a value that must retrigger the effect every time it is changed so you have to put it in the dependency array. Apart from that though you have a few things in your code that are getting re-instantiated or re-invoked on every render. For example, the filter() function or the extraction of components from ant. Extraction of components is better to be moved outside of the component scope and the filter() function is better to be moved inside your effect or inside a useMemo()

Comment: Do you mean to put  "const filterAuthor = appState.filter((item) => item.author === AuthorBlog)" inside use effect like this:
inside     
const [appState, setAppState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
  axiosInstance.get("/").then((res) => {
   const allBlogs = res.data;
   setAppState(allBlogs);
  });
        const filterAuthor = appState.filter((item) => item.author === AuthorBlog) ;
 }, [setAppState]);
When I try this way, I get an Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've written in the comments - adding `slug` to the dependency array of your `useEffect` fixed the problem.

Why is that?
Dependency array in `useEffect` hook is used to rerun the hook when one of these variables changes. In your case, changing the url, changes the slug so the component should load new data.

I would even remove `setData` from this array, because it doesn't do anything as `useState` setters don't ever change.

```
useEffect(() => {
  laxiosInstance.get(slug).then((res) => {
    setData({ posts: res.data });
  });
}, [slug]);
```